# How can i delete single line item in xero invoice using pyxero in python?

Tags: python, xero-api

How can i delete single line item in xero invoice using pyxero in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation suggests that you would GET the invoice contents, and POST the invoice again having removed the lineitem. The implication is that the other lines must have their LineItemID fields present so that Xero "knows" they already exist.

"Not providing an existing LineItem with it's LineItemID will result in that line item being deleted."

I read that as saying you would re-submit the invoice with all the other lineitems present, with their LineItemIDs, and that would force is to remove the missing line(s).